# Regular expressions to query json and xml data

Tags: json, regex, xml

I have two files, one is j.json and the other is x.xml, I want to fetch/query some data from both files. Is it possible to do this using regex? currently, I am using jq for querying data from JSON file. I was planning to use regex for Querying XML data,but then this above doubt came across my mind. It would be super easier for me if i use same library for both json and XML.

PS- i don't want to transform files, json-to-xml or vice versa.

Thank you.

Comment: XPath 3.1 can query both JSON and XML data, it is available with SaxonJS 2 for both client-side as well as server-side (node.js) JavaScript, as well as with Saxon HE for the Java and the .NET platform or with SaxonC for C/C++ with Python and PHP extensions. XQuery 3.1 is a superset of XPath 3.1 and can therefore query and manipulate both JSON and XML data and is implemented in databases like BaseX or eXist-db.

Comment: @MartinHonnen snap!

Comment: @MartinHonnen hey thanks for the response! I just came across this library called xq, thinking of using it instead.

Answer (score 0):

For some simple XML and JSON documents it may be feasible, but you can't *in general* parse XML or JSON with regular expressions.

[Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

If you want to use the same technique or toolset to parse both data formats, you might want to look at XPath 3.1 as a query language: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/

Saxon is an interpreter you can use to execute XPath 3.1 queries: https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!xpath-api